# Einstein to make sales predictions

Tags: einstein-analytics, einstein

I have a customer who wants to be able to predict how much each of their Accounts is going to buy in the upcoming months. They believe that the amounts are determined by a number of factors e.g. past sales, size of customer's company, industry etc.

Taking a load of data, then making predictions when we don't know how to weight the different factors seems like a perfect use-case for a machine-learning algorithm.

So, now that I come to search the documentation on Einstein, it seems like it still only works on two domains: vision, and language. It doesn't seem to offer direct access to an ML algorithm.

Is that correct? We're still pretty much just [identifying hot dogs](https://www.theverge.com/2017/6/26/15876006/hot-dog-app-android-silicon-valley)?

It looks like Einstein Analytics might do what I want - predicting future numbers. But it comes with many more tools than we need and a [$75/user/month cost](https://www.salesforce.com/ap/editions-pricing/einstein-analytics/), and I'm not sure if it can take into account all the other factors.

Does anyone know if Salesforce plan to offer generalised ML to us at some point? I'm a bit tempted to just used something like [Google's ML](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/), then integrate to it via REST.

Comment: Were you thinking of something like Einstein Prediction Builder? Seems like it fits that use case - https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/prediction_builder

Comment: Thanks - that seems to come under Einstein Analytics now and is pretty close to what we're after. Definitely worth giving it a trial to see if it works for us.

Answer (score 0):

i have completed that trailhead 
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/prediction_builder

well you can test in your trailhead playground that  has auto enable all the permission set and licence need to work on prediction builder

In order to  use it in your org or any, you need to pay 74$/user/permonth